# ActiveRecords [something] belongs_to [User] and has_many [Users]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many, belongs-to

I'm modelling a scenario with `Users` and `Tools`, where a `Tool` is owned by one `User` but can be used by many `Users` including to one owning it.

I was thinking about adding an `owner_id` column to `Tools` and say it `has_many` Users or by adding a new relationsship table.

I'm really new to Rails and I have problems setting up the right associations in the models though, maybe you can point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your should add `owner_id` to the `Tools` table.
Associations will be like that.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tools
end

class Tool < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

You'll need a `tools_users` table in order to use habtm-association. Generate a migration and create a table with option `id: false` and two columns `user_id` and `tool_id`:

```
class CreateToolsUsersTable < ActiveRecordMigration
  def change
    create_table :tools_users, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :tool_id
      t.integer :user_id
    end
  end
end
```

After that you can call something like `@user.tools` or `@user.owner`
Read more [there](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. How would I go about the `Tool` being owned by one `User` but modelling, that it can used by many `Users`, too? Right now, it can only be used by one `User`, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Im not sure, since im not testing this, but im believe that you can define owner as `@tool.owner = @user` and if you want add just usual users to the tools `@tool.users << @user`. Oh and instead of `belongs_to :user` you need `has_many_and_belongs_to_many :users` association

Comment: You'll need a tools_users  table in order to use habtm-association. Generate a migration and create a table with option id: false and two columns user_id and tool_id :)

Comment: Yes, good point @theodorton. I will add this into answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

User has many tools
Tool belongs to user in owner
Tool has many users

is what I would do.
I'm not sure about the wording because I don't use Active Record but this is how it works in other orms